# Extract embedded font from Powerpoint ppt

Tags: powerpoint, truetype

I have a ppt with a font embedded. The thing is that I want to create a word file...therefore I need the font that is inside the ppt.

Does anybody know how to extract it?

Thanks

Comment: Is the file `.ppt` or `.pptx`?

Comment: There's no simple way to do this.  Or rather, if the font's developer allows distribution, it'll happen automatically.  When you open the file, the font will be installed on your PC.  If they allow limited distribution (ie, editable embedding), then the font will be available only when the PPT is open, possibly available to other programs at the same time; not sure of that.  But font embedding was never intended as a mechanism for (illegally) distributing fonts.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your answer. Yes...I've noticed what you are saying. It looks really impossible to extract it...probably due to the fact that this is designed for protecting Copyright. Don't worry...I am only using it to obtain a Creative Commons font that is on some old slides...but that I can't find anywhere.
I am sure there is a way. I will keep looking!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Found it! Save it as PDF. Then use [Mutool](http://mupdf.com/) to get it:

```
c:\> mutool.exe extract filename.pdf # (on Windows) 
$> mutool extract filename.pdf # (on Linux, Unix, Mac OS X)
```